# How to place an image to the far right end of a button?

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I have a button that has a down arrow image inside of it. I am trying to place the down arrow image to the far right end of the button [image]

I tried to use `ImageEdgeInsets` with a Force `right-to-left` semantic but with no use as I can't make it dynamic on every screen size .

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a proportional constraint for the button and you can make an if statement for the button for hiding and showing the imageView.[image]

Comment: can you show me how and what to add? I am new to xamarin.ios

Comment: Updated the answer for you.